# Typescript - Options Object or Builder

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, builder

So, I'm trying to implement "Options Object" in typescript that I read is an alternative to Java Builder pattern.

I saw that I can use builder, but it seems much more complex to implement than "Options Object" which provides similar thing with less code.

This is something I would like to achieve:

```
class OptionsObject {
    private readonly name : string;
    private readonly no? : number;

    constructor(o : OptionsObject){
        this.name = o.name;
        this.no = o.no;
    }

    uradi() : void{
        console.log(`Number is ${this.no} and name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

const p = new OptionsObject({
    name:"asd",
    no:11
} as unknown as OptionsObject); //works but no type-safety
p.uradi();

//standard java builder
//const p2 = new OptionsObjectBuilder().name("asd").no(11).build();
```

I would like to pass to `new OptionsObject` only properties that I need. This way as it is now - it works but I have no type safety. I would not like to introduce additional `interface`, since then I would need to duplicate properties.

Is there any better way to do this with type-safety, or is there any other pattern similar to builder that is adapted to typescript?

Comment: "*I would not like to introduce additional interface, since then I would need to duplicate properties.*" not if you actually structure things properly, though. There is no duplication if you have `interface OptionsObject {name: string, no?: number}` and then `OptionsObjectImpl extends OptionsObject`. However, I'm not clear on what that options object should be doing as it accepts...itself in the constructor? And also has some method that does stuff. Options objects are dumb containers equivalent to POJOs. Also, options objects in Java are the same.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, but in that case properties need to be public. I would like to have encapsulated properties here. You are right that it is similar to Java POJO, but there are some differences as I can see - like easily making properties mandatory or optional.

Comment: But what is your goal here? Because the `OptionsObject` show here is neither an options object, nor a builder. So, I don't really know what you're trying to do. You *can* create a builder and it *can* be type-safe. It's also not really needed because you can just have the options object as an interface. If you're concerned with code size, that's a lot less code than creating a builder class *and* using it.

Comment: My goal is to see what is best alternative to Java builder pattern in JS. So with minimal amount of code I would like to create immutable objects and specify which properties are  optional etc.

Comment: [Here](https://repl.it/repls/CyanRemoteCareware#index.ts) is how an implementation of a builder can look like. However, it's radically different than yours. I had to come up with the design because your example doesn't make much sense. It's a closed loop - it requires an instance of itself to initialise itself. Furthermore it's an options object but the consumer is itself. Typically these are different. A builder is also separate from both the consumer and the options object.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a nice use case for Typescript utility type `Partial<T>`

Example from [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt)

```
interface Todo {
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

function updateTodo(todo: Todo, fieldsToUpdate: Partial<Todo>) {
    return { ...todo, ...fieldsToUpdate };
}

const todo1 = {
    title: 'organize desk',
    description: 'clear clutter',
};

const todo2 = updateTodo(todo1, {
    description: 'throw out trash',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're telling typescript that constructor takes in an object of the type `class<OptionsObject>`.

`OptionsObject` isn't a plain javascript object like the one you're trying to pass in.

Regarding this:

> I would not like to introduce additional interface, since then I would need to duplicate properties.

You're not really duplicating properties, you're defining a contract. If you're not familiar with the `composition` design pattern, there are several books that cover it, including Head First Design Patterns and Clean Architecture, both available on your choice of reading platform.

**To answer your question, however:**

The only way to achieve what you want is with an interface. I have an example below, but technically, you wouldn't *have* to implement the interface, and you could just use it as a type for your argument. By implementing the interface, the private member variables must become public since and interface members are always public.

```
interface OptionsObject {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly no?: number;
}

class OptionsObjectImpl implements OptionsObject {
    readonly name: string; // cannot be private due to being part of the interface
    readonly no: number;

    constructor(o : OptionsObject){
        this.name = o.name;
        this.no = o.no;
    }

    uradi() : void{
        console.log(`Number is ${this.no} and name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

const p = new OptionsObjectImpl({
    name:"asd",
    no:11
}); //works with type-safety

p.uradi();
```

Hopefully, this helps.

EDIT: Adding without implementation as an example.

```
interface OptionsObjectInterface {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly no?: number;
}

class OptionsObject {
    private readonly name: string; // cannot be private due to being part of the interface
    private readonly no: number;

    constructor(o : OptionsObjectInterface){
        this.name = o.name;
        this.no = o.no;
    }

    uradi() : void{
        console.log(`Number is ${this.no} and name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

const p = new OptionsObject({
    name:"asd",
    no:11
}); //works with type-safety

p.uradi();
```

Comment: I don't thing there is `composition` as a design pattern. I think that is a principle (favor composition over inheritance).

Comment: exactly that - I would like not to repeat properties in OptionsObjectImpl, and also I do not want to use readonly o : OptionsObject; and I would like for properties to be private.

Comment: @Jackques - I know about composite. But it has nothing to do with this...

Comment: @Jacquesジャック composite !== composition. It's a subset, only for when you have "a bunch of stuff" that you want to model to work together. Say, a canvas with many shapes that you can move collectively.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you're asking for something that isn't possible because you cannot have something be both a class and a normal object without using an interface.

Comment: Sorry, linked the first google result. I've always considered composition a design pattern, but that's a discussion for a different day.

Comment: It's late, I'm heading to bed. You have three options. 1. The way you're already doing it. 2. Implementing an interface. 3. Using an interface as the type just for the constructor arg. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If we'd look at the concept of Builder Pattern we'd see several simple things consisting the approach:

- the builder object;
- the 'build' method which *validates options* and builds a new object based on them;
- the main object class;

So, all the difference of the TypeScript approach is that we use *plain javascript object* as a builder object, because we don't need to write a class describing it like we'd do it in Java. But we still need a type-safety, so we'll just define a type of the builder object.

In addition, we'll implement our 'build' method as a static method of the main object class.

And this is what we get:

```
class MyObject {
    private constructor(readonly prop1: string, readonly prop2: number) {
    }

    // an alternative to the 'build' method
    static createInstance(builder: MyObjectBuilder): MyObject {
        // some validation...

        return new MyObject(builder.prop1, builder.prop2);
    }
}

// We make all props optional to allow specify
// them at any moment as if it would be a builder
type MyObjectBuilder = {
    prop1?: string,
    prop2?: number
};
```

Usage:

```
let builder: MyObjectBuilder = {};

builder.prop1 = 'text';
builder.prop2 = 7;

let myObject = MyObject.createInstance(builder);
```

Of course, in some cases it would be enough to pass builder straight to the public constructor of our class, but it will not be a complete alternative to the Builder Pattern because it doesn't only provide a way to pass options to an object constructor, but also gives us the full control over the building of an object (on the level higher than the level of the object itself).